# How to deploy beanstalk Django app that someone else has created?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My team mate has created a beanstalk django app and got to the point when he can successfully deploy using the eb tool.

We would like to work collaboratively such that we both can deploy to the same beanstalk application from our own machines.

On running eb init I got the application my friend has created listed, which is great. But, after I choose the existing application, eb list does not show existing application's environments.

eb status reports an **ERROR**: "this branch does not have a default environment".

eb create does not let me to choose an existing environment name, so it's somehow aware that it exists.

What is the proper way for deploying into the same beanstalk application from different machines ?

Comment: I recommend to use API CLI instead: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/OperationList-cmd.html 
If it doesn't work - check IAM permissions.

Comment: What version of eb are you using? Run `eb --version`. Also, what IAM credentials are you using for this? Did your friend create a separate user for you to use?

Comment: We have eb ver - 3.2.1 and yes, he created a separate user for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that this is due to permissions. However before I continue, check for these things.

- Are you using the same region as your friend?
- Is the environment still running? Did your friend shut it down?
- Make sure the account you are using is a child account of your friends.

Assuming everything else is set up correctly, the only reason you wouldn't see the environment is due to IAM permissions. When your friend created a user, he needed to assign permissions to the user. The permissions might not allow you to view the environment.

Once all permissions are set up correctly, this should work. `eb list` should show the environments, and `eb init`/`eb use` should select one to use, and `eb deploy` would deploy to the same environment.